# building DNS server on linux redhat 7.x

Tags: rhel, dns, resolution, resolv.conf

we are using until now DNS server based on WIN 2000

we decided to move to DNS server that will replace the DNS server on Linux

note - DNS server on linux redhat should also support revers lookup

I see some suggestion as described in the post - [How to setup a named DNS service on Redhat 7 Linux Server](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-named-dns-service-on-redhat-7-linux-server)

but we want to be sure that we choose the best and the right DNS server for rhel 7.x

we'll happy to get other suggestion for DNS server on linux redhat 7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is around "want to be sure that we choose the best and the right DNS server for rhel 7.x".

This seems to be an opinion based question.

My opinion is that as you've paid for RHEL license, might as well use the `bind` RPMs that come with RHEL.

You've got commercial support there, you can raise support cases with RH vendor directly, plus RH will be shipping fixes to the product throughout the RHEL 7 lifecycle.

Comment: do you have documentation for bind ?

Comment: we have registration to download any redhat rpm , so we need just the procedure -:)

Comment: what you think about this procedure - https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/configure-dns-bind-server-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

Comment: Your original question isn't about the procedure.  Or about bind documentation. Your original question is which DNS is best on RHEL. If you've further questions, probably worth creating a new post.

Comment: mmm I worry if I open new question then maybe some user will say this is duplicate question